# Where to store the tables to grant privilege to a new user in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, privileges

I am working an assignment project for university. Where I have four users admin, user, organizer and sponsor.

Now I don't want "ALL" privileges to all users. For example I want to set only select privilege to organizer for table FEST.

I know how to grant privilege to user from the SYSTEM user in oracle 10g. But I'm confused where to store the tables like FEST. Should I store under the user SYSTEM or organizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table that is created is already stored in the database.

If you are looking to store the table_name for the purpose of tracking, which user was granted which privilege on which table, that is also available in data dictionary views.

If you are looking for something else, kindly be more specific.

Thanks.

Comment: When I create a table I create it under a specific user after connecting it.
Like- 
conn system/password
and after that 
create table fest .... 
So, I'm asking- Where will I create the table? Connecting in system/ Created user Organizer?

Comment: If FEST is an application table, it needs to be created under the application user who is supposed to own the table. Any other user who needs access to that table, will obtain it through a GRANT statement. This is purely technical. But from a design point of view, we don't create application tables based on who has what privilege on that table. Rather that goes by application requirements and design. For understanding how to manage roles and privileges kindly go through the OracleDoc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm)

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thank you for your time and answer. :)